# PhpStorm 10, don't indent after enter key pressed

Tags: phpstorm, auto-indent

I'm wanting PhpStorm to put the caret on the beginning / left margin of the new line when I press the enter key. Currently it indents the line according to the code above, which I don't want it to do. I've dug through settings and tried multiple things, but have yet to figure out how to turn this off.

This is how it looks. I have the caret at the end of the line:
[image]

I press the enter key, it indents on the next line (which I don't want it to do):
[image]

This is how I want it to function (the caret is on the left margin, no tabs were added):
[image]

Any ideas on how to get this to function this way?

Comment: `Settings/Preferences | Editor | General | Smart Keys --> Enter | Smart Indent` -- try disabling this option.

Comment: That's one of the first settings I disabled :-/ Here's a screenshot of that page: http://content.screencast.com/users/PureFS/folders/Jing/media/7954f8b9-450e-44eb-8965-d5ce0a66f102/2015-12-04_1201.png

Answer (score -1):

Preference->Editor->Code Style->PHP->Other->check "indent code in PHP tags".

Comment: Add some explanation with answer for how this answer help OP in fixing current issue

Comment: Does not have anything to do with the question.